# How can I associate letters with numbers in a text, keeping their positions?

Tags: string-manipulation

I would like to ask you how I can associate a letter with a number in Mathematica. 
I have a text/string, let's say `sentence="hello world!"`, and I would like to substitute each character with a number. 
So what I am looking for is something like this:

```
h-> 1
e-> 2 
l -> 3
l-> 4
o -> 5
(space) -> 6
w-> 7 
and so on
!-> 12
```

Of course, the text that I am considering contains more than 12 characters, so I cannot do it manually. 
Could you help me to understand which function I should consider/create to do that?

Many thanks

Comment: does `ToCharacterCode[sentence]` give what you need? or  `AssociationThread[Characters[sentence],ToCharacterCode[sentence]]` ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `string = "hello world!"; Range[StringLength[string]]` which outputs the numbers 1 through 12 in a list? If you're looking for actual replacement rules, how should the code determine what numbers should be associated with repeated characters (like the "ll" in "hello")?

Comment: `Rule @@@ Transpose[{Characters@sentence, Range@StringLength@sentence}]`

Comment: Thanks to all for your help and answers. I was looking for something like what Bob Hanlon suggested. How can I list the associations as in ToCharacterCode (without arrows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

```
 MapIndexed[# -> #2[[1]] &, Characters[sentence]]
```

> {"h" -> 1, "e" -> 2, "l" -> 3, "l" -> 4, "o" -> 5, " " -> 6, 
>    "w" -> 7,
>      "o" -> 8, "r" -> 9, "l" -> 10, "d" -> 11, "!" -> 12}

To get the numbers only the simplest way is what @MassDefect suggested in a comment above: `Range @ StringLength @ sentence`.

**Original answer:**

You can use [`ToCharacterCode`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToCharacterCode.html):

```
ToCharacterCode[sentence]
```

> {104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33}

```
FromCharacterCode[%]
```

> "hello world!"

```
Normal @ AssociationThread[Characters[sentence], ToCharacterCode[sentence]]
```

> {"h" -> 104, "e" -> 101, "l" -> 108, "o" -> 111, " " -> 32, 
>         "w" -> 119, "r" -> 114, "d" -> 100, "!" -> 33}

```
List @@@ Normal @
  AssociationThread[Characters[sentence], ToCharacterCode[sentence]]
```

> {{"h", 104}, {"e", 101}, {"l", 108}, {"o", 111}, {" ", 32}, {"w", 
>       119}, {"r", 114}, {"d", 100}, {"!", 33}}

Alternatively,

```
DeleteDuplicates @ Thread[{Characters[sentence], ToCharacterCode[sentence]}]
```

or

```
Thread[{#, Flatten @ ToCharacterCode[#]}] & @ DeleteDuplicates[Characters @ sentence]
```

both give

> {{"h", 104}, {"e", 101}, {"l", 108}, {"o", 111}, {" ", 32}, {"w", 
>     119}, {"r", 114}, {"d", 100}, {"!", 33}}